# Can a Flex application detect its own URL?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a Flex application (Web, not Air) meant for mass distribution, to be included like a plug-in at various websites.

- Can a particular instance of the SWF detect its own URL?
- If so, what ActionScript commands might be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

Check [IBrowserManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html)

Answer (score 6):

loaderInfo.loaderURL gives you the SWF url in your document class.

You can also do this but it's dependent on allowScriptAccess in the embed code:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) // import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
{
 try
 {
  url = String(ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString"));
 }
 catch(s:Error)
 {
  url = loaderInfo.loaderURL;
 }
}
```

That will give you the actual page url if it's able to.  In my experience with widely distributed games in Flash you can't really rely on allowScriptAccess being set to enable this method.  Your miles may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the SWF URL and accessing the URL of the page enclosing the SWF are two very different things.

[Application.url](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#url) will give you the SWFs URL.  The [Flex 4](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Application.html#url) Application has the same property.

There is no guaranteed way to get the URL of the loading HTML page, but you can use ExternalInterface to do so on some situations.  ( @Ben's answer is spot on there ).